# Selenium - undesired form filling - Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am relatively new to Python, and tried my hand at Selenium to download 5 years QoQ historical financial records for 800 companies. Was quite happy with the results, but needed quite a bit of manual work arounds to get what I wanted ( which I eventually got ).

Strange thing though, sometimes it filled in the search Company with a string which was not even in the python ( ie in Numpy was ie "IP", but in the field it seacrhed for "ARIP". I suspect its using the first item in the drop downlist instead of the item typed in. (see below ) [image]

please dont laugh too much about the attached code, I am not a pro, but it works and thats all that matters.

Any advice / teaching / changing code so I can learn would be appreciated.

ps - Tried Selenium several times. Never worked. Stumbled on a three in Stackoverflow about Xpath, and it worked like a charm !

```
import selenium
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from pandas import DataFrame
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import os
import shutil
import glob


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('MyURL')

username_input = '//*[@id="username"]'
password_input = '//*[@id="password"]'
login_submit = '//*[@id="login-btn"]'


driver.find_element_by_xpath(username_input).send_keys('MyLogin')
driver.find_element_by_xpath(password_input).send_keys('MyPwD')
driver.find_element_by_xpath(login_submit).click()

time.sleep(10)

dropdown = driver.find_element_by_id("menu-Company")
dropdown.click()


driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Financial Statements"]').click()

companyname=[]

companyname=['ABPIF','AJA','ALLA','ALT','ALUCON','AMA','AMANAH','AP','AQUA','ARIN','B','BC','BM','CHAYO','CHEWA','CHG','CI','CIG','CIMBT','CITY','CK','CKP','CM','CMC','CMO','CNS','CPW','CRANE','CRD','CSC','CSP','CSS','CTARAF','CTW','CWT','D','DDD','DELTA','DEMCO','DIF','DIMET','DOD','DOHOME','DREIT','DRT','DTAC','DTC','EA','EASON','EASTW','ECF','ECL','EE','EGATIF','EGCO','EIC','EKH','EMC','EPCO','EPG','ERW','ESSO','ETE','EVER','F&D','FANCY','FE','FLOYD','FMT','FN','FNS','FORTH','FSS','FTE','FVC','GAHREIT','GBX','GC','GCAP','GEL','GENCO','GFPT','GIFT','GJS','GL','GLAND','GLOBAL','GLOCON','GOLD','GOLDPF','GPI','GPSC','GRAND','GREEN','GSC','GSTEEL','GTB','GULF','GUNKUL','GVREIT','GYT','HANA','HARN','HFT','HREIT','ICC','ICHI','ICN','IFEC','ILM','IMPACT','INET','IP','IT','J','K','KC','KKC','M','MC','ML','MM','NC','NDR','NETBAY','NEW','NEWS','NEX','NFC','NINE','NMG','PE','PF','PG','PICO','PK','PL','PRO','PT','PTG','RAM','ROCK','RPC','RS','S','SC','SE','SMART','SR','STA','STAR','STC','T','TC','TH','THAI','TM','TR','TRT','TRUE','TSE','TSI','TTA','TU','U','UP','UT','VI','VL','WG','WORK','WP','WR']

Counter=0

for name in companyname:
    Counter=Counter+1
    print('Name:',name)
    companyfield='//*[@id="input-search"]'
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(companyfield).send_keys(name)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(companyfield).send_keys(u'\ue007')

    if Counter == 1:
        # Give some time to set web page ie qoq, from and to date, and Profit and Los or Balance sheet
        time.sleep(30)
    elif Counter==30:
        time.sleep(20)    # give web site a breather
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="export-link"]').click()

    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(companyfield).clear()

    # Strangely, if over 100 xlsx downloaded , it plays up - so move out to other folder and restart counters 
    time.sleep(0.3)
    if Counter==70:
        files = glob.iglob(os.path.join("/Users/cg/Downloads", "*.xlsx"))
        for file in files:
            if os.path.isfile(file):
                ts = time.time()
                shutil.copy2(file, "/Users/cg/Python/junk/SETScrape/Output1/"+str(ts)+".xlsx")                         


        files = glob.glob("/Users/cg/Downloads/*.xlsx")
        for f in files:
            os.remove(f)   
        Counter=2
```

[image]